# Is there a website similar to "State of JS" for Python?

Tags: python

Is there a website generating reports similar to "State of JS" for Python?

It compares and visualises various frameworks, libraries, features, trends based on surveys.

Its graphs are perfect for market research decisions, hence "software recommendations".

https://stateofjs.com/

For example: https://2020.stateofjs.com/en-US/technologies/

I wonder if something similar exists for Python.

Doesn't have to be the same fancy visualisations. Just something that  presents the market technology trends in Python based on statistics and surveys.

Answer (score 0):

A good one I found is JetBrains' "The State of Developer Ecosystem": https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/devecosystem-2021/python/

`Python Programming - The State of Developer Ecosystem in 2021 Infographic | JetBrains: Developer Tools for Professionals and Teams`

They also have such infographics for other languages on the menu.